# Quartz jobs hanging around in DB tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

We are using Quartz 2.1.6 for job scheduling on a cluster, and storing the job data in a JDBC jobstore in our MySQL database (MySQL 5.1).

All our Quartz configuration (scheduler, jobs, triggers) is done at startup through Spring.  We store the data in the database for clustering purposes.

Problem:  We have several jobs that were added and then deleted from the Quartz configuration.   They are no longer in the config, but they are still present in the tables.   How do we get rid of them?    Reading the Quartz documentation, it appears that doing manual edits of the tables is a Very Bad Thing.

We do not appear to be explicitly setting JobDetail.setDurability(true), so I'm not sure why these jobs and triggers are hanging around, but they are.

Anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it's not the best idea to do this in the database unless you're very on clear what you're doing. So, try doing it programmatically:

```
ISchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
IScheduler schedulder = factory.GetScheduler();

schedulder.DeleteJob(JobName, JobGroup);
```

Comment: Yep, we tried it with naked SQL, and sure enough, had problems.   Kind of like brain surgery with a dull knife.   Better to use the provided tools.